# Get path of dropped file in cocoa application

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, file

I wondering how you would retrieve the path of the file that a user has dragged and dropped into a cocoa application. For example: User drags a file named test from his/her desktop. Then the cocoa application would say: Users/currentusername/Desktop/test

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just downloaded [Apple's "CocoaDragAndDrop" sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/CocoaDragAndDrop/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10000384) and tried it out.

When I drag in a PNG file from the Finder into the running app, the title of the window changes to the path of the image that was dragged in.

Looking inside the sample code, I can see a file URL is included in the Pasteboard:

```
 //if the drag comes from a file, set the window title to the filename
 fileURL=[NSURL URLFromPasteboard: [sender draggingPasteboard]];
 [[self window] setTitle: fileURL!=NULL ? [fileURL absoluteString] : @"(no name)"];
```

Try this technique in your own code and modify it for taste.

Comment: This is not working anymore with Xcode 6... any tip?

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is no longer working with Xcode 6.
I've found this methode to get the same result:

```
    NSURL*fileURL = [NSURL URLFromPasteboard: [sender draggingPasteboard]];
    NSString *filePath = [fileURL path];
    [[self window] setTitle:filePath];
```

Comment: What should we do if there're several files dropped?

Answer (score 1):

Currently working on developing a similar interface, I’ve understood that the OP had asked for **path**, not URL retrieval. It seems the suggested OS X 10.10 (XCode6) workaround for the accepted answer has issues in refusing to drag and drop content between windows.

However, avoiding declaring NSString *filePath, but simply substituting the [fileURL absoluteString] method with [fileURL path] method in line 175 of DragDropImageView.m of the suggested sample code instead, seems to solve it:

```
    fileURL=[NSURL URLFromPasteboard: [sender draggingPasteboard]];
    [[self window] setTitle: fileURL!=NULL ? [fileURL path] : @"(no name)"];
```

It compiles and runs as devised in Xcode4 through Xcode6, SDK 10.8-10.10, AFAICT.

Hope this can help.